# How to Fix This MySQL Query So It Works?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1093

I have the following query:

```
UPDATE lessonstatus
INNER JOIN user ON lessonstatus.user_id = user.user_id
SET user_id = (SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE username = 'too_many_accounts')
WHERE last_name = 'stupid' 
AND first_name = 'user'
AND username != 'too_many_accounts'
AND lessonstatus.lesson_id NOT IN (SELECT lesson_id FROM lessonstatus WHERE user_id = 1);
```

However, I get the following error when trying to execute it:

```
Error Code : 1093
You can't specify target table 'lessonstatus_rtab' for update in FROM clause
```

How would I fix this query so that it works?

Comment: Terminology tip: "refactoring" is changing the design of code without modifying the functionality. Fixing broken code isn't called "refactoring".

Comment: Andrew, that's true. What would be the correct term to define 'fixing broken code'?

Comment: I would keep it simple and use the word "fix."  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't `SELECT` from a table (even in a subquery) that you're updating in the same query.  That's what the error "can't specify target table" means.

But you can join `user` and `lessonstatus` multiple times in the `UPDATE` statement, and use the join criteria creatively to pick out the individual row you want.

The way to simulate `NOT IN` with a join is to do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.  Where the right side of that join is not matched, that's where `NOT IN` would be true.

```
UPDATE lessonstatus l1
  INNER JOIN user u1 ON (l1.user_id = u1.user_id)
  INNER JOIN user u2 ON (u2.username = 'too_many_accounts')
  LEFT OUTER JOIN lessonstatus l2 
    ON (l1.lesson_id = l2.lesson_id AND l2.user_id = 1)
SET l1.user_id = u2.user_id
WHERE u1.last_name = 'stupid' AND u1.first_name = 'user'
  AND u1.username != 'too_many_accounts'
  AND l2.lesson_id IS NULL; -- equivalent to "l NOT IN l2"
```

**nb:** I have tested this query for syntax, but not with real data.  Anyway, it should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

There are more errors ("user" table and "user_rtab" alias do not match, use of non-qualified field names is not recommended), but UPDATE syntax itself should be similar:

```
UPDATE lessonstatus
SET user_id = (SELECT TOP 1 user_id FROM user WHERE username = 'too_many_accounts')
FROM lessonstatus
    INNER JOIN user ON lessonstatus.user_id = user_rtab.user_id
WHERE last_name = 'stupid' 
    AND first_name = 'user'
    AND username != 'too_many_accounts'
    AND lessonstatus.lesson_id NOT IN (
        SELECT lesson_id FROM lessonstatus WHERE user_id = 1
    );
```

Comment: This might work in MSSQL Server or another engine, but it does not work in MySQL.

Comment: "TOP" is a Microsoft/Sybase extension to SQL and it is not supported by MySQL.  And even if it did, this has nothing to do with the error in the original query.

Comment: I somehow did read subject as "MSSQL Query", sorry. Will try better next time :)